How would I access nested routes with a sticky header in React Native Navigation 6?
I'm trying to get nested routes so I can show and hide the categories on my header. I know I can access a route by specifying the header within the stack navigator but its constantly jumping/flickering between screens when navigating and I just want the header to be sticky with the categories only showing on the home screen and nowhere else.
Is there a way I can stop this flickering and keep the header sticky? The way I have it currently with the header at the top of the stack is working fine but I just can't filter the categories. I have removed animation and this works but decreases the performance of the app quite a lot. I also tried setting the background to stop the flickering in the navigation containers theme but this is still causing the header to jump slighting.
Also anytime I useRoute or useNavigationState, it gives me the current tab I'm on and not any nested routes.
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from '../../components/screens/HomeScreen';
import CompetitionScreen from '../../components/screens/CompetitionScreen';
import NotificationScreen from '../../components/screens/NotificationScreen';
import WinnersScreen from '../../components/screens/WinnersScreen';
import TicketsScreen from '../../components/screens/authentication/TicketsScreen';
import CartScreen from '../../components/screens/CartScreen';
import PaymentScreen from '../../components/screens/PaymentScreen';
import CheckoutScreen from '../../components/screens/CheckoutScreen';
import CheckoutConfirmationScreen from '../../components/screens/CheckoutConfirmationScreen';
import PaymentSuccessScreen from '../../components/screens/PaymentSuccessScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../../components/screens/authentication/LoginScreen';
import Header from '../Header/Header';
import {useNavigationState, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class HomeStack extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Header removeCategories={false} />
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerMode: 'screen',
          }}>
          <Stack.Screen key={'home_screen'} name={'home_screen'} options={{}}>
            {props => <HomeScreen {...props} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'tickets_screen'}
            name={'tickets_screen'}
            component={TicketsScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'competition_screen'}
            name={'competition_screen'}
            component={CompetitionScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'winners_screen'}
            name={'winners_screen'}
            component={WinnersScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'notification_screen'}
            name="notification_screen"
            component={NotificationScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'cart_screen'}
            name={'cart_screen'}
            component={CartScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'checkout_screen'}
            name={'checkout_screen'}
            component={CheckoutScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'payment_screen'}
            name={'payment_screen'}
            component={PaymentScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'payment__success_screen'}
            name={'payment_success_screen'}
            component={PaymentSuccessScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'checkout_confirmation_screen'}
            name={'checkout_confirmation_screen'}
            component={CheckoutConfirmationScreen}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            key={'login_screen'}
            name={'login_screen'}
            component={LoginScreen}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default function (props) {
  const routes = useNavigationState(state => state.routes);
  const currentRoute = routes[routes.length - 1].name;
  console.log(currentRoute);
  return <HomeStack {...props} />;
}

import {Text, StyleSheet, View, Platform, Dimensions} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import AccountStack from './Stacks/AccountStack';
import HomeStack from './Stacks/HomeStack';
import OptionsStack from './Stacks/OptionsStack';
import WinnerStack from './Stacks/WinnerStack';
import Home from '../../assets/icons/tabs/home.svg';
import Options from '../../assets/icons/tabs/options.svg';
import Tickets from '../../assets/icons/tabs/tickets.svg';
import User from '../../assets/icons/tabs/user.svg';
import Winners from '../../assets/icons/tabs/winners.svg';
import {BlurView} from '@react-native-community/blur';
import TicketStack from './Stacks/TicketStack';
import AuthStack from './Stacks/AuthStack';
import {Context} from '../context/UserContext';
import Header from './Header/Header';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

class TabNavigator extends Component {
  static contextType = Context;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await this.context.checkIsLoggedIn();
  };

  render() {
    const {competitions, isLoading, winners} = this.props;
    const {state} = this.context;

    return (
      <>
        <Tab.Navigator
          initialRouteName="home_tab"
          screenOptions={{
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#231F208C',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-around',
              alignItems: 'center',
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: 1,
            },

            tabBarBackground: () => (
              <View style={{width: '100%', height: '100%', overflow: 'hidden'}}>
                <BlurView
                  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                  blurType="dark"
                  blurAmount={5}
                  reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
                />
              </View>
            ),
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="home_tab"
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: () => null,
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <Home
                    width={25}
                    height={25}
                    stroke={focused ? '' : 'white'}
                    fill={focused ? '#E91E63' : 'transparent'}
                  />
                </View>
              ),
              headerShown: false,
              // header: ({navigation}) => <Header />,
            }}>
            {() => (
              <HomeStack
                winners={winners}
                competitions={competitions}
                isLoading={isLoading}
              />
            )}
          </Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="winners_tab"
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: () => null,
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <Winners
                    width={25}
                    height={25}
                    fill={focused ? '#E91E63' : 'white'}
                  />
                </View>
              ),
              header: ({navigation}) => <Header />,
            }}>
            {() => <WinnerStack winners={winners} />}
          </Tab.Screen>
          <Tab.Screen
            name="tickets_tab"
            component={state.token ? TicketStack : AuthStack}
            options={{
              // headerShown: false,
              tabBarLabel: () => null,
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <Tickets
                    width={30}
                    height={30}
                    fill={focused ? '#E91E63' : 'white'}
                  />
                </View>
              ),
              header: ({navigation}) => <Header />,
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="auth_tab"
            component={state.token ? AccountStack : AuthStack}
            options={{
              // headerShown: false,
              tabBarLabel: () => null,
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <User
                    width={25}
                    height={25}
                    fill={focused ? '#E91E63' : 'white'}
                  />
                </View>
              ),
              header: ({navigation}) => <Header />,
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="options_tab"
            component={OptionsStack}
            options={{
              // headerShown: false,
              tabBarLabel: () => null,
              tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                  <Options
                    width={25}
                    height={25}
                    fill={focused ? '#E91E63' : 'white'}
                  />
                </View>
              ),
              header: ({navigation}) => <Header />,
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iconContainer: {
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 20,
  },
});

export default function (props) {
  return <TabNavigator {...props} />;
}

